# @Environment(\.presentationMode) triggers many (unnecessary?) view reloads in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Assume, you have a view hierarchy of (minimal example below).

`Outer (Navigation)View` -> `(Pushed) ContainerDetailView` -> `(Embedded) View`

Clicking a `NavigationLink` in the outer view, pushes a detail view which includes an embedded view. If you put some `print` statement in the `init` function to see how often views are loaded, all is well and as expected (1 print for each view).

However -- here comes the question -- if you include

`@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>`

in the middle view, it will reload (init new objects) of the embedded view many times. In the minimal example it is 3 times. **Why is that?** I can only suspect that it has something to do with pushing something on the navigation stack internally, changes the environment variable which leads to an invalidation of the middle view's view body and therefore triggers a reload of the child view.

It however gets even better if the `(Embedded) View` has a `.toolbar` modifier. If that is the case, the view is `ìnit`ed 5 times in total for being pushed just once on the stack. **Why is that and can it be avoided?**

Here is a minimal example (I got this behavior on Simulator and Device in XCode 12 and iOS 14.5).

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SomeSwiftyTestApp: App {
    
    let items = [1,2,3,4]
    
    /* This is the outer view */
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                            NavigationLink("Click Here", destination: ContentView())
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}

/* This is is the middle view */
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    init() { print("ContentView loaded") }
    
    var body: some View {
        InnerView()
    }
}

/* This is the inner view */
struct InnerView: View {
    
    init() { print("InnerView loaded") }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            /* Comment this toolbar modifier in to get 5x loading instead of 3x */
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(id: "id", placement: .principal, showsByDefault: true, content: {
                    Text("ToolbarItem")
                })
            })
    }
}
```

If you run this and push a button, you get

```
ContentView loaded
ContentView loaded
ContentView loaded
ContentView loaded
InnerView loaded
InnerView loaded
InnerView loaded
InnerView loaded
InnerView loaded
```

Where `ContentView loaded` is expected due to eager `NavigationLink` loading. But I would have assumed to see `InnerView loaded` just once. Am I doing something wrong? Can this be avoided as my (actual) view hierarchy is fairly complex and starts background processing on `init`.

Comment: Not an issue. SwiftUI view values might be created many times - it is up to rendering engine and not controlled from our side.

Comment: So your answer to "Why is this" is "it is by design". However, if my `init` in InnerView is doing expensive things (eg. start an HTTP request), performance degrades very quickly. The consequence would be to make sure that everything you do in `init` ing your views is as cheap as possible and do expensive things only in `onAppear`? Is there any documentation that clarifies this?

Comment: *init in InnerView is doing expensive* - don't do it in view, there should be view model for this with initiated request on first get or something.

Comment: @Nicolas I can’t point to documentation, but I will say that the SwiftUI engineers echoed the advice about never doing anything expensive in init to me in the WWDC labs this year.

Comment: Actually it's the same advice which exists for decades in UIKit/AppKit: *Don't do expensive controller related things in the **view***

Comment: One reference is within the [Modeling Model Data in your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app?changes=latest_minor) section. "SwiftUI might create or recreate a view at any time, so it’s important that initializing a view with a given set of inputs always results in the same view" You should do this kind of work in a `@StateObject` and if you need work done upon `init` do it when the StateObject initializes

Comment: Follow up-question: The culprit here is that the view is invalidated if the `@Environment` variable changes. However, my view is not actually dependent on the state of that variable. Is it possible to have the value of the environment variable injected but not have it react like a `@State` but more like a `@Binding`?

Comment: Any update here, I'm facing same issues @Nicolas

Comment: Same problem here, I have middle views reloading when using @Environment(\.presentationMode) and I can't find any good documentation on how to do this.